# How a chain of function calls is evaluated

Tags: lua

```
...
print(a.b():c():d())
...
```

When and how will the chain of calls be evaluated? I see two options:

- When interpreter reaches the line, so any future calls of print() here work only with the last d().
- When print() actually accesses the argument, so the whole chain is evaluated every time the line is executed (the desired behavior, BTW).

Comment: No, I really want the chain the way I wrote it.

Comment: 1. The "chain of calls" (`a.b():c():d()`) is an irrelevant distraction: the question is whether or not the `print` argument is evaluated more than once. 2. You could have tested this faster than you could have posted the question. 3. This is the way it works in every programming language. 4.  The "interpreter" doesn't  "reach this line"; the lexer reaches that line, tokenizes it, feeds the tokens to the parser, which then emits bytecode. It's the bytecode that's interpreted (see: lhf's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole chain is evaluated every time the line is executed.

The precise set of instructions is shown by giving the line in question to `luac -l`:

```
1   [1] GETTABUP    0 0 -1  ; _ENV "print"
2   [1] GETTABUP    1 0 -2  ; _ENV "a"
3   [1] GETTABLE    1 1 -3  ; "b"
4   [1] CALL        1 1 2
5   [1] SELF        1 1 -4  ; "c"
6   [1] CALL        1 2 2
7   [1] SELF        1 1 -5  ; "d"
8   [1] CALL        1 2 0
9   [1] CALL        0 0 1
10  [1] RETURN      0 1
```

The code above assumes that `a` is a global variable. It'll be slightly different if `a` is a local variable.